# In SQL, How to display a student who is taking more than one subjects?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example - Table name = TABLE

```
StudentID | SubCode | SubName
-----------------------------
    1          M1       Math
    1          S1       Science
    1          E1       English
    2          H1       History
    3          G2       Geography
    4          M1       Math
```

Can we display the answer like this ?

```
studentid | SubCode | SubName
---------------------------------
    1          M1       Math
    1          S1       Science
    1          E1       English
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `IN()` subquery with a `HAVING` clause should do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE StudentID IN (
  SELECT 
    StudentID
  FROM table
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 1< (SELECT COUNT(studentID)
FROM table);
...is that the same thing as this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
  FROM YourTable AS T1
       INNER JOIN YourTable AS T2
          ON T1.StudentID = T2.StudentID
             AND T1.SubCode <> T2.SubCode;
```